# Почему не работает код который генерирует PDF с HTML?

Tags: javascript

Использую html2canvas.js и jsPDF:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let elem = document.querySelector('#step_three .content');

    $('#download-pdf').click(function(){
        html2canvas(elem, {
            onrendered: function(canvas){
                let img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                let doc = new jsPDF();
                doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20,20);
                doc.save('hogo.pdf');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

В консоли вижу вот такую картину, но окно для сохранения файла не появляется:

```
173f65022b1 1ms Starting document clone  html2canvas.js:2377:35
173f65022b1 1443ms Document cloned, using computed rendering html2canvas.js:2377:35
173f65022b1 1444ms Starting DOM parsing html2canvas.js:2377:35
173f65022b1 1465ms Added image file:///C:/Users/Igor/Desktop/fiverr/Progects/Abkane/Hogo%E2%84%963/hogo_livr_Jul24-1/img/bulle_contact.png html2canvas.js:2377:35
173f65022b1 1539ms Added image file:///C:/Users/Igor/Desktop/fiverr/Progects/Abkane/Hogo%E2%84%963/hogo_livr_Jul24-1/img/library.png html2canvas.js:2377:35
173f65022b1 1543ms Added image file:///C:/Users/Igor/Desktop/fiverr/Progects/Abkane/Hogo%E2%84%963/hogo_livr_Jul24-1/img/pdf.png html2canvas.js:2377:35
173f65022b1 1549ms Added image file:///C:/Users/Igor/Desktop/fiverr/Progects/Abkane/Hogo%E2%84%963/hogo_livr_Jul24-1/img/calculator.png html2canvas.js:2377:35
173f65022b1 1653ms Added image data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20class%3D%22highcharts-root%22%20style%3D%22font%3A%20400%2012px%20%26quot%3BLucida%20Grande%26quot%3B%2C%20%26quot%3BLucida%20Sans%20Unicode%26quot%3B%2C%20Arial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20sans-serif%3B%20--blue%3 html2canvas.js:2377:35
173f65022b1 1701ms Added image file:///C:/Users/Igor/Desktop/fiverr/Progects/Abkane/Hogo%E2%84%963/hogo_livr_Jul24-1/img/3d.png html2canvas.js:2377:35
173f65022b1 1731ms Added image file:///C:/Users/Igor/Desktop/fiverr/Progects/Abkane/Hogo%E2%84%963/hogo_livr_Jul24-1/img/step_three_img.jpg html2canvas.js:2377:35
173f65022b1 1736ms Added image file:///C:/Users/Igor/Desktop/fiverr/Progects/Abkane/Hogo%E2%84%963/hogo_livr_Jul24-1/img/page_up_white.png html2canvas.js:2377:35
173f65022b1 1758ms Starting renderer html2canvas.js:2377:35
173f65022b1 1760ms Canvas renderer initialized (1288x1194 at 28,194) with scale 1 html2canvas.js:2377:35
173f65022b1 3341ms Finished rendering html2canvas.js:2377:35
```

​